# How to do 'stwithin' command with ServiceStack OrmLite on Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, geography, ormlite-servicestack

I'm completely new to using OrmLite.  So how do I efficiently select geographic points around a given set of coordinates on sql server using service stack and ormlite.

(Normally I would use a 'stwithin' command on a spatially indexed 'geography' type).

Please can anyone provide a lovely example that utilises OrmLite (SQL server version and maybe a Postgre-SQL version too) using the new API so its strongly typed and good coding practice - this would bootstrap my understanding immensely ...thankyou in advance  :)